# Trying to list different registries

Tags: java, mysql, select, between

I'm trying to list a range of entries from my BD, those entries consist of different kinds of forms, some examples:

i have 5 types of forms:

```
15C00001
15B00001
15D00001
15M00001
15A00001
```

And i want to be able to list every single one of them, but i cant use the LIKE statemt in the query cause im using the BETWEEN statement aswell i have been trying with the underscore (_) and (%) expressions in the query but its pointless.

```
SELECT *
FROM Registry
WHERE Registry.Registry BETWEEN 15%10000 AND 15%10005
```

That query has to list the following forms:

```
15C00001
15B00001
15D00001
15M00001
15A00001
15C00002
15B00002
15D00002
15M00002
15A00002
15C00003
15B00003
15D00003
15M00003
15A00003
15C00004
15B00004
15D00004
15M00004
15A00004
15C00005
15B00005
15D00005
15M00005
15A00005
```

Comment: Why do you want 15C00002?  It is not one of your five forms.

Comment: It's an example, the number of the registry can be 15C00002 or 15C10001.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
where registery rlike '^15[CBDMA]0000[1-5]$'
```

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for, but it seems that you want a specific set of three characters at the beginning of `registry` and the values 1-5 at the end.

The wildcards `'%'` and `'_'` are only used with `LIKE`.  For this purpose, regular expressions may be more appropriate.